Maven transitive dependency shows older version even though parent package is updated within dependencyManagement
I have the following POM (not the complete file):
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    <spring.boot.version>2.4.0</spring.boot.version>
    <spring.boot.starter.web.version>2.5.15</spring.boot.starter.web.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.starter.web.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.starter.web.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

When I run:
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework:spring-webmvc -Dverbose

I get the following output:
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- dependency:3.6.1:tree (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] com.example:demo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.5.15:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.1:compile (version managed from 5.3.27)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

The issue here is even though I have overriden spring-boot-starter-web in dependencyManagement and declared it before spring-boot-dependencies, the version of spring-webmvc being used is still 5.3.1 and not 5.3.27 or am I misundersanding the meaning of (version managed from 5.3.27).
The version 2.5.15 of spring-boot-starter-web uses the version 5.3.27 of spring-webmvc. I am required to use this version because of vulnerability concerns detected by a package scanner.

Don't mix modules from different versions of a framework, that will only lead to problems, upgrade the whole of Spring Boot instead.

@M.Deinum I wish I could, but upgrading the framework to the version which contains the desired version of spring-webmvc breaks the test cases. I agree with you though that the whole framework needs to be upgraded to maintain consistency

Then fix that. Don't upgrade parts as that will lead you down a path of hard to debug errors, memeory issues, performance issues and more undesirable side effects. Also don't start upgrading only spring-webmvc (as suggested in the answer). While that might seem to work might not work with all the other related dependencies leading to what I mentioned initially.

I'd remove the spring-boot-starter-web and declare spring-web there instead. You got it right, it has to be before spring-boot-dependencies BOM import.
Another thing that I've done on projects where I'm stuck on SB 2 was adding a BOM import for Spring and Spring Security, as spring-boot-dependencies BOM no longer ships with updates, so I could still update for vulnerability fixes.
        <!--
         need to override spring and spring-security versions as they are vulnerable and no updates
         are coming from spring-boot-dependencies anymore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>


I tried replacing spring-boot-starter-web with spring-web in dependencyManagement and I still got the same version of spring-webmvc being used which is 5.3.1 instead of the desired version of 5.3.27.

Do you have a parent pom as well, too? This would have an impact on dependency resolution.

No. For this sample code, there is no parent. The pom given above is all there is. Except for the other meta such as name, description, artifactId, groupId, etc.

OK, replace spring-boot-starter-web with spring-webmvc in the dependencyManagement section and that will be enough.

However, if you want to have both spring-web and spring-webmvc at the correct version, use spring-framework-bom BOM import, as in my answer and this will work.

% mvn dependency:tree | grep web
[INFO] - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  - org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.39:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.37:compile
[INFO]    - org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.37:compile

This is with spring-framework-bom 5.3.37 and spring-boot-dependencies 2.4.0 in dep mgmt section.

Adding spring-webmvc directly in the dependencyManagement does work, but in the actual project which I'm working in, it breaks the build (some methods are undefined) which is why I resorted to updating spring-boot-starter-web

I added spring-framework-bom 5.3.37 to the dependencyManagement section and it still shows org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.1:compile with mvn dependency:tree | grep web

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
